# How to read text file and save it in excel sheet using asp.net c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have one text file with the below structure

10180,65,395, 
10182,65,395,
10183,65,395,
10185,65,395,

I need that after read the text file, the cell in the excel sheet contains the value as below

fristcell, secondcell, thirdcell

10180          65        395

means after the commas the value placed in the new cell.

I read the text file with the commas, but not get how to insert it or import data in excel.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since want to write to an excel file and save it and considering that your scenario is not too complicated, I would recommend [Closed XML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) which is a wrapper around [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Go through the Closed XML documentation. That should help you get started.

The general way I would go about this is :

1. Read the text file into a `List<string>`.

2. Create a file using Closed XML.